# How to get scipy remez to give matlab firpm answer?

Tags: matlab, filter-design, scipy

If I run this in matlab:

```
h = firpm(100,[0 0.1 0.2 1],[0 0 1 1])
```

and this in scipy:

```
h = remez(100,[0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5],[0, 1])
```

I think I'm asking for the same thing, but the results are totally different and the scipy response is garbage. What am I doing wrong?  I don't need the results to be exact, just similar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The firpm and remez commands return symmetric linear phase filter solutions. In order to create a symmetric linear phase high pass filter, you must have an odd number of taps (Type 1 filter, see chart below). An even number of taps with a symmetric filter will have a zero at Nyquist and thus you can't (successfully) create a high pass.

In the Matlab `firpm` command as entered with N=100, the first parameter N is the order of taps in the filter (one less than the number of taps) so will result in an odd number of taps as required, while in the Python scipy.signal `remez` command, the first parameter N is the  number of taps and thus for N=100 will come out as an even number which can't be realized. Confirming this, if you increase N by one in Matlab you will get the same (bad) result. Or similarly, if you increase N by one in the Python example you will get the same (good) result.

Matlab doc: "b = firpm(n,f,a) returns row vector b containing the n+1 coefficients of an order-n FIR filter."

Python doc: "Parameters
----------
numtaps : int
The desired number of taps in the filter. The number of taps is
the number of terms in the filter, or the filter order plus one."

[image: Linear Phase Filter Types]

As a simplest confirmation / demonstration of the forced zero location for Type II (always has a zero at $z=-1$ or Nyquist) and Type IV (always has a zero at $z=1$ or DC) I have added the graphic below:

[image: example Type II and Type IV FIR filters]